# How to remove file DSN by ODBC API using C++

Tags: c++, api, odbc

I use SQLWriteFileDSN to create ODBC file DSN. Now what I want to do is to remove the DSN.
Based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403313.aspx, I have tried to use SQLConfigDataSource to do it, but it always returns 0 and dsn file is not deleted.

driver: Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)

function call: SQLConfigDataSource(NULL, ODBC_REMOVE_DSN, "Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)", "DSN=filedsnname");

Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do this via ODBC?

Surely, you just need to delete the *file* using whatever mechanism C/C++/C# provides...

I am not a programmer so I cannot give you a code sample.

Comment: Sure, file DSN is nothing but a file. If I wanna delete the file, I need to find out the directory where the file locates first of all. In WIndows Vista or above, no way to get the directory in registry table.

Comment: Now I have a workaround, which is to provide full path of dsn file instead of only dsn file name in SQLWriteFileDSN.